# How to assign JSON image value to HTML img tag

Tags: javascript, html, json

This is the full url that successfully displays the image.

http://openweathermap.org/img/w/04d.png

Note than the JSON property "icon" provides the value "04d" and it's up to me to throw that into a url in order to use it.

> Just as a reference, to show that the JSON path is correct, here is how I successfully displayed text from the same JSON property that the image is stored in.
>
> document.getElementById("weatherDescriptionData").innerHTML = data.weather[0].description;

This is the HTML img tag

```
<img src="" id="weatherIconData"></div>
```

This is the first method I tried unsuccessfully to show the image. (scroll right)

```
document.getElementById("weatherIconData").src = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + data.weather[0].icon + ".png";
```

This is the second method I tried unsuccessfully to show the image.

```
$("#weatherIconData").prop('src', "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + data.weather[0].icon  + ".png");
```

I checked and found that

```
console.log(data.weather[0].icon);
```

does in fact return 04d.

How would one display the image provided in the JSON in an HTML view?

Comment: @PencilCreate I edited [@user6101582's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36236176/227299) to add some more detail. The accepted answer may work but it's not the correct solution since it works around a problem that wasn't really understood. There's no reason why `$('#id')` should be used over `document.getElementById('id')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try jquery .attr

```
$("#weatherIconData").attr('src', 'http://openweathermap.org/img/w/' + data.weather[0].icon  + '.png');
```

your html tag also starts as an `<img>` but closes with `</div>` close this with `<img id="" src="" />`

```js
$(function() {
  var data = {
    weather: [{
      icon: '04d'
    }]
  };
  
  $("#weatherIconData").attr('src', 'http://openweathermap.org/img/w/' + data.weather[0].icon + '.png');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="" id="weatherIconData"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't typically downvote working answers, but this was a wild attempt that worked out of luck, correctly closing the `img` tag would do the trick

Answer (score 3):

You did not close the `<img />` tag.

```
<img id="weatherIconData" />
```

jQuery may have worked around the problem but is not the correct solution as @user2950720 suggested. There's no reason why `$('#id')` should be used over `document.getElementById('id')`

```js
var data = {
  weather: [{
    icon: '04d'
  }]
};

document.getElementById("weatherIconData").src = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + data.weather[0].icon + ".png";;
```

```html
<img src="" id="weatherIconData">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `attr` over `prop` . **[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/13yft015/)**

```
$("#weatherIconData").attr('src', "....");
```

Comment: I upvoted. You offered the correct answer, even if user2950720 offered it first. Thanks.